# implementing auto suggestions on every key pressed

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, wxpython, multiprocessing

I am implementing a text box with an auto suggest values which takes values from mysql database on every key pressed.As i have large set of values in database,my functions takes time.Moreover each call to a function is run sequentially

Suppose
I pressed A key,which triggers an event and execution of func starts.
Then i pressed B key,which again triggers an event but now i want earlier func should be killed before running the second function

How can i achieve this??

On searching through i found threading can be used to implement this.But still i wasnt able to implement even through threads.If someone know the exact procedure?

Comment: Database call for every keypress?  Yikes.  Can't you just store this in memory?  (ps use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree))

Comment: No,my database is large and i have to filter the results for every key pressed

Answer (score 1):

This was used as a great (in my opinion) job interview question, and Nathan Leclaire [wrote about it on his blog](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/11/16/the-javascript-question-i-bombed-in-an-interview-with-a-y-combinator-startup/).

Relevant excerpt:

> if we use window.setTimeout we can delay the call for 200 milliseconds. ... But that’s not going to help us in the case where the user is typing fast, or even just normal speed. So we need a way to interrupt the timeout if the user keeps typing.

...

> So, I know that when you call `window.setTimeout`, you get back an ID that uniquely references the timeout. And you can use it to cancel the timeout if need be! So we should just store the timeout ID in the keypress function closure, and if the user triggers a keypress event again before the timeout function triggers, we’ll just cancel it and set a new one!

And finally, he shares some a code example, which, I imagine could help you optimize your function!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').keypress(function() {
    if (this.timeoutId)
      window.clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    this.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
      $.ajax({
          // do some stuff
      });
    }, 200);
  });
});
```